# I have build a MERN CRUD app with with registration,login,logout functionality using JWT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, crud, mern

[Login page made with react](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OhDjgt_C8brh9R6eIZQ4r7_8pWZv1HYTK0YQonxjQO4/edit?usp=sharing)I have successfully implemented registration,login and logout functionality using JWT in my project but I want to show a user's(who is logged in) info under "My Account" section. I tried but facing a weird issue---Instead of showing info of user who has loggged-in, My Account section & browser console is showing info of some other user. For example, if Adam has logged in, info(name & email) of Emily is being displayed, if john has logged-in info(name & email) of Emily is being displayed. If I delete Emily's data from db, the next in list  of users's info will be shown.[image: Some other user has logEmily is first in db and if I delete her, the next in the user list will be shownged-in but info of Emily is being shown]

This is the schema of Users....

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const registerUser = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    },

    email:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    },

    password:{
        type: String,
        require:true,
    }

})

export default mongoose.model('Registration',registerUser)
```

** https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cX8Xhu4GZ2wUS2LnXmXHg6f-8ZC1lZPIchBT6S4FUhA/edit?usp=sharing

**  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1COAobok_82J5lTYOdZMQLQYeOg7PdTIyxQblJl8DcgA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This isn’t sufficient to understand the issue. Please post code of jwt generation - how is the user data being stored,  and logged in user profile api code - how is it being fetched.

Comment: as @VasundharaMehta said you should provide more information, and code snippets used to perform the login, validation of the jwt, etc...

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cX8Xhu4GZ2wUS2LnXmXHg6f-8ZC1lZPIchBT6S4FUhA/edit?usp=sharing

This is the google-drive link of my user-controller code.  If you need something else please let me know.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OhDjgt_C8brh9R6eIZQ4r7_8pWZv1HYTK0YQonxjQO4/edit?usp=sharing

This is the login page in frontend..

Comment: Ideally, the snippets should be added in the question itself and not external links @VP1996

Comment: Also, not the login page in frontend, but essentially we need to see what logic is being used for jwt creation and the login API / user profile data fetch backend code